# Microsoft Graph APIs not returning Calendar Events

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph APIs in my MVC Application to fetch, create, update and delete Calendar Events. I am facing the following two problems in achieving this task:

1. I already have an OWIN Authorization in my system, which is conflicting with Azure AD Authorization. Can two Authorizations simultaneously run, and if yes, how?
2. Even if I somehow get the Azure AD token and try to use it to fetch events, the async function gets stuck at the `await` statement and does not return any output in my System, although the same works well in a stand-alone application. What could be wrong in my System?
3. How to convert the JSON string returned from API using `ReadAsStringAsync()` function into a `List<>` of `Microsoft.Graph.Event` type object?

All help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I already have an OWIN Authorization in my system, which is conflicting with Azure AD Authorization. Can two Authorizations simultaneously run, and if yes, how?

In your case, you have your own Identity Server, which means you can use [Get Access without a user.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

As the official document mentioned, you can run it as a background services or daemons.

We can get access token from this background services when we need it and use it to call Microsoft Graph.

> Even if I somehow get the Azure AD token and try to use it to fetch events, the async function gets stuck at the await statement and does not return any output in my System, although the same works well in a stand-alone application. What could be wrong in my System?

Could you please provide the sample code for Positioning problem?

> How to convert the JSON string returned from API using ReadAsStringAsync() function into a List<> of Microsoft.Graph.Event type object?

If when we get the response string, we can use the following code to convert the string into a `List<>` of `Microsoft.Graph.Event` type object

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(responseString);`